# Lack of Randomness in Map Generator

Tags: c#, random, grid, graphics2d

I am trying to generate random numbers 0-49.  I want to draw the links in a grid as long as the random number is not 0.  Every time I do get a 0, it is followed by another ten 0s (give or take).  In my research, they said this would be the problem if I kept creating new instances of my Random, but I am not doing that.  My code is as follows:

```
//Class begins
    namespace Mascape
    {
        public class Game1 : Game
        {
            GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
            SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
            Wall[, ,] walls = new Wall[2, 15, 10];
            int mapWidth=15;
            int mapHeight=10;
            Random rand = new Random();  //Outside of any methods or loops.
            int mapFullness;
```

//The following is in my Initialize() method

```
//i is horizontal vs. vertical link
//j is the x position of the link
//k is the y position of the link


        mapFullness = 50;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mapWidth; ++j)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < mapHeight; ++k)
                {
                    if (!(rand.Next(50) == 0))
                    {
                        walls[i, j, k].active = true; //Links are drawn if active
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

I am trying to draw a grid with randomly missing links. The objective is to have them spread out, appearing about one in 50. This is the actual result:

[image]

Any idea why the randomness is lacking?  Let me know if you would like more info, please.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I thought I was very clear in this question.  I have done my research too.  Please let me know so I don't repeat the mistake.

Comment: A subtractive random number generator algorithm is used to generate random numbers. So your numbers will be evenly distributed even though it is possible to predict the next number generated using the same seed. Hmm I can think why every time you get a 0, it is followed by another ten 0s. Instances of System.Random created in close proximity produce identical sequences of random numbers so watch our for instance creation in loops. But I dont see any instance creation loops in code you posted.
Is this multithreaded?

Comment: @GeorgePhilip i have not done anything with threading, but I am using a MonoGame template (OpenGL)

Comment: I thought I recognized that template. Still, you should probably be doing this kind of thing in its own class, rather than in the main game loop. Also, those walls do seem to have some lone 0s, so I don't know if I'm seeing the problem. This looks like a perfectly valid outcome.

Comment: @Magus the 4th column for example, is 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 all in a row.  I want a new random number generated for each link.

Comment: What isn't random about a chain of 0s? It doesn't seem likely, but at the same time you can't argue that it isn't random.

Comment: No need to downvote this question.

Comment: @Magus the image is just one instance.  I have run it about 20 times with consistent results

Comment: Identical results, or similar results?

Comment: Similar.  Never the same result twice.  But always grouped together.

Comment: `Random` is definitely doing it's job correctly. If I were you, I would test other parts of the code to make sure they're working properly as well. Perhaps making a predefined array of numbers 0-49 like `int[] predefArray = new int[50] { 0, 1, 2, ... , 49 }`, then take values from this array instead of calling `Random`. Something like, `for (int k = 0; k < mapHeight; ++k) if (predefArray[k] != 0) walls[i, j, k].active = true;`. After that, go over your picture and make sure that only the portions where `k` was 0 is where you don't have a wall.

Answer (score 0):

There should be more to this. See the following code copied from yours generate random as expected.

```
        Random rand = new Random();
        int mapWidth = 5;
        int mapHeight = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mapWidth; ++j)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < mapHeight; ++k)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rand.Next(50));
                }
            }

        }
```